# Finding All Defined Functions in Python Environment

Tags: python, function

Is there a method to find all functions that were defined in a python environment?

For instance, if I had

```
def test:
   pass
```

`some_command_here` would return `test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import inspect
import sys


def test():
    pass

functions = [name for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isfunction)]
print functions
```

prints:

```
['test']
```

Comment: Definitely the nicest way proposed so far +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `globals()` to grab everything defined in the global scope of the file, and `inspect` to filter the objects you care about.

```
[ f for f in globals().values() if inspect.isfunction(f) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `globals()` and `types.FunctionType`

```
>>> from types import FunctionType
>>> functions = [x for x in globals().values() if isinstance( x, FunctionType)]
```

Demo:

```
from types import FunctionType
def func():pass
print [x for x in globals().values() if isinstance(x, FunctionType)]
#[<function func at 0xb74d795c>]

#to return just name
print [x for x in globals().keys() if isinstance(globals()[x], FunctionType)]
#['func']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def test():
...     pass
...
>>> [k for k, v in globals().items() if callable(v)]
['test']
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we will create the `test` function we want to find.

```
def test():
    pass
```

Next, we will create the `some_command_here` function that you want.

```
def some_command_here():
    return filter(callable, globals().values())
```

Finally, we call the new function and convert the filter into a `tuple` for viewing.

```
tuple(some_command_here())
```

**Note:** This searches the current global namespace and returns anything callable (not just functions).

---

**Example:**

```
>>> def test():
    pass

>>> def some_command_here():
    return filter(callable, globals().values())

>>> tuple(some_command_here())
(<function test at 0x02F78660>,
 <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>,
 <function some_command_here at 0x02FAFDF8>)
>>>
```